# Using Azure Service Bus in a user subscription model

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

How would you go about using Service Bus in a scenario where only client applications with unexpired subscriptions can receive messages from the service bus? Let's say you have a paid service where users can buy subscriptions to your messages for a period of time, so you want your service bus to send new messages only to a selected group of clients (clients with active subscriptions). It is much preferred if authorization for this is done on the server side and not on the client app. Looking at the service bus models (queues, topics, relays), none of them seem to fit this use case.

One way I was thinking to implement this was to change the SAS Key every day and get client applications to query the SAS key from a Web API. So only clients with valid subscriptions can refresh their SAS and receive from the service bus. I don't know if SAS could be changed through the API, though.

Is there any better support for this kind of scenario in Azure Service Bus, or can you think of a better way to implement it?

Comment: I was of the understanding that you could create a SAS, and give it a "long" expiry time, and that at the time the client no longer has an active subscription, you can revoke their SAS server side.  Each client gets their own SAS (you seem to imply that there's a single SAS that all clients share?)

Comment: The problem with having a SAS per client is that the number of SAS you can create is limited to twelve (at the namespace root level or at messaging level.) Creating a queue per client also seems to be too much redundancy.

Comment: Can you not publish your service through the Azure Marketplace like this one here https://datamarket.azure.com/application/0c8b6224-5f21-40dd-9841-8f91627123b0. This will then handle subscriptions / limits etc.

Comment: An example of SAS key rotation can be found here https://dzimchuk.net/post/implementing-service-bus-sas-keys-rotation

Comment: I'm thinking maybe [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is better suited for my use case.